# Sails.js - How to update model with associations

Tags: sails.js, waterline, model-associations

I am trying to work with Models with associations. I have two models defined as following:

**User.js**

```
module.exports = {schema: true, attributes: {
   userId: {
       autoIncrement: true,
       type: integer,
       primaryKey: true,
   },
   userId: {type: integer},
   email: {type:string, size:200},
   addressId: {
      model:UserAddress
   }
}
```

**Address.js**

```
module.exports = {schema: true, attributes: {
  addressId: {
     autoIncrement: true,
     type:integer,
     primaryKey:true
  },
  userId: {type:integer},
  address: {type:string, size:250}
}
```

So far, I was able to CREATE records in both models by POSTing following JSON to

```
http://localhost:1337/user/

{
    "userName": "John",
    "userId": "3",
    "email":"john@hotmail.com",
    "addressId": {
        "userId": "3",
        "address": "123 abc street"
     }
 }
```

I was able to UPDATE both records using PUT with this URL:
`http://localhost:1337/user/update/1`and JSON below, note that I have added **addressId** in the nested JSON in this case.

```
{
    "userName": "John",
    "userId": "3",
    "accountLogin":"john@hotmail.com",
    "addressId": {
        "addressId":1,
        "userId": "3",
        "streetAddress": "123 abc street"
     }
}
```

However, when I first created a record in the User table without an address and later wanted to add it, I had no luck to make it work. What I did was using PUT against `http://localhost:1337/user/update/1` with following JSON, since the address is new, there's no addressId.

```
{
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "accountLogin":"john@hotmail.com",
    "addressId": {
        "userId": "3",
        "streetAddress": "123 abc street"
     }
}
```

Is there a way to do what I was trying to do in Sails.js? I could just Post to `http://localhost:1337/address` to create a new record, but I want to make my API consistent is possible. The more serious problem is, when above JSON was sent, it crashed the backend. It seems to me that user can easily crash backend by sending invalid JSON, how would I protect backend from this kind of crashing?

Comment: I was just thinking about your question and came up with one things which may help further investigation : which adapter are you using and did you try with another adapter.

Comment: I am using mysql. The error message does not look like adapter related, it says: "/jzj/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/nestedOperations/update.js:532
    this.create(record).exec(function(err, val) {
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'create'
    at createRecord (/Users/mcheng/jzj/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline ... node_modules/async/lib/async.js:125:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/Users/mcheng/jzj/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)"

Comment: can you try when using waterline default primary keys and also you are not exactly using a one to one association as you do not have association reflection in your address as your "userId" field stands for an integer however it should be a proper "user" `userId : { model : user }`

Comment: What does your `update` code look like? Are you using `User.find`, or are you using `User.update`?

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

In order to add a new object to a collection within an object you can use the sails built in (blueprint) "add" method. I checked sails documentation on the website but was not success full however if you check the `add` blueprint in the github repository it does exactly what you are lookiung for.

Here is what says the method description :

```
 /**
 * Add Record To Collection
 *
 * post  /:modelIdentity/:id/:collectionAttr/:childid
 *  *    /:modelIdentity/:id/:collectionAttr/add/:childid
 *
 * Associate one record with the collection attribute of another.
 * e.g. add a Horse named "Jimmy" to a Farm's "animals".
 * If the record being added has a primary key value already, it will
 * just be linked.  If it doesn't, a new record will be created, then
 * linked appropriately.  In either case, the association is bidirectional.
 *
 * @param {Integer|String} parentid  - the unique id of the parent record
 * @param {Integer|String} id    [optional]
 *        - the unique id of the child record to add
 *        Alternatively, an object WITHOUT a primary key may be POSTed
 *        to this endpoint to create a new child record, then associate
 *        it with the parent.
 *
 * @option {String} model  - the identity of the model
 * @option {String} alias  - the name of the association attribute (aka "alias")
 */
```

And to answer your next question yes there is also a remove method ;)

You can find more info there : https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions

Comment: Thanks MrVinz, I was hoping that CRUD handles this situation automatically. It is just an update operation on the client and the client should not need to know how the address is stored on the backend. The biggest problem is, as I mentioned at the end of my post, if client simply call update in this case, it crashes the server. I would love to know how this kind of errors (errors occurred in CRUD) can be handled.

Comment: Continue on my previous comment, the "add" method only works for collection type of association (one to many). The blueprints API reference on sailsjs.org mentioned that for one to one association, simply use Update (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Update.html). But it did not give an example of updating an existing record and add a new association at the same time.

Comment: When your server crashes are you getting any error ?

Comment: see my comment to my original post above.